# Trying to send a POST-request with urllib.request returns the same page

Tags: python

I'm trying to send a POST-request to [this site](http://www.altenheim-adressen.de/schnellsuche/index.cfm) to perform a search in their database, but it just returns the same page, not the page I'm looking for. If I try to access the site the search leads to with my parameters, it denies my request. I feel like I'm missing something, maybe someone can help me out.

```
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

DATA = urllib.parse.urlencode({'plz_ff': 50000, 'plz_ff2': 50030})
DATA = DATA.encode('utf-8')

request = urllib.request.Request("http://www.altenheim-adressen.de/schnellsuche/index.cfm", 'POST')
# adding charset parameter to the Content-Type header.
request.add_header("text/html;charset=UTF-8","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0")
f = urllib.request.urlopen(request, DATA)

soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

print(soup.prettify)

f.close()
soup.close
```

EDIT2:  The Code works now, many thanks. I had to adjust the search parameters to adress `suche1.cfm`, and it now returns the result I'm looking for. This is the finished product:

```
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

params = {
'name_ff': '',
'strasse_ff': '',
'plz_ff': 50000,
'plz_ff2': 50030,
'ort_ff': '',
'bundesland_ff': '',
'land_ff': '',
'traeger_ff': '',
'Dachverband_ff': '',
'submit2' : 'Suchen'
}

DATA = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
DATA = DATA.encode('utf-8')

request = urllib.request.Request(
"http://www.altenheim-adressen.de/schnellsuche/suche1.cfm",
DATA)
# adding charset parameter to the Content-Type header.
request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")
request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0")
f = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

print(soup.prettify)

f.close()
```

Comment: `soup.close` does nothing (it searches for a tag called `<close>`) but you don't need to close a BeautifulSoup tree. `soup.prettify()` would need to be *called*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `DATA` to the `Request` object; you are sending the text `'POST'` as a post body instead now.

The correct method would be:

```
request = urllib.request.Request(
    "http://www.altenheim-adressen.de/schnellsuche/index.cfm",
    DATA)
# adding charset parameter to the Content-Type header.
request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")
request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0")
f = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

Note that I also added *User-Agent* and *Content-Type* headers there; whatever you were adding was not a recognisable header.

I do note that the 2 forms on this page use *different* targets; neither posts to `index.cfm`:

```
>>> for form in soup.find_all('form'):
...     print(form.attrs.get('action'))
... 
suche1.cfm
suche1b.cfm
```

so if you expected to use one of these forms you'll need to use the correct target URL here. You'd also need to verify your POST form fields; I see that the form posting to `suche1b.cfm` has *similar* form fields, but they use `plz_ffb` and `plz_ff2b`, not `plz_ff` and `plz_ffb`.

You'll likely also want to send *all* form fields, even with empty strings:

```
params = {
    'name_ffb': '',
    'ort_ffb': '',
    'strasse_ffb': '',
    'plz_ffb': '50000',
    'plz_ff2b': '50030',
    'land_ff': '',
    'rubrik_ff': '',
    'submit22': 'Suchen'
}
DATA = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
DATA = DATA.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I replaced my code with yours and tried to post to `suche1.cfm` and `suche1b.cfm`, but it returns a HTTP 500 Error.

Comment: @FreshPrince: perhaps they were expecting at least empty values for the other fields too?

Comment: @FreshPrince: passing in all fields produces a 200 OK response.